# MKPointAnnotation will not show title-Very strange behaviour

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add title to the annotation ,but i don't see it when hit the relevant point on the map .

To add it i use :

```
  for( NSDictionary *dic in [GlobalData sharedGlobals].currentBusinessList)
    {
        NSString *title=[dic objectForKey:@"name"];
        double latitude=[[dic objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
        double longitude=[[dic objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);

        MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        MKPinAnnotationView *pointV = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:point reuseIdentifier:nil];
        [point setCoordinate:location];
        point.title = title;
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:pointV.annotation];


        MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
        region.center = location;
        region.span.longitudeDelta /= 5.0;
        region.span.latitudeDelta /= 5.0;
        [self.mapView setRegion:region];

    }
```

Now this works great. but you can't set the colour here-it will not work, but only if i add the callback here to set the colour :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
             viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{


        MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    //point.title=@"ran"; also not working
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        annView.animatesDrop=YES;
        return annView;
}
```

but than seems that adding this one will prevent from the title to show up.

Seems that i can get only one of them, title ,or colour.
If i take out the second method here, i can see the title, but than, setting the colour in the first method will not work .

What is the right way to put a few annotations with title and colour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can change the color and display the title. your code looks good so far but add this line to `(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
             viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation`

```
pinAnno.canShowCallout = YES;
```

Comment: wow thanx !you solve my problem. but why they do things like that? why i have to add this and its not obvious ?

Comment: it becomes obvoius when reading [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/canShowCallout)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that conforms to NSAnnotation Protocol and use it instead of using the MKPointAnnotation

Create your own Class for example `MyAnnotation`

**MyAnnotation .h file**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title andSubTitle:(NSString *)subtitle atCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

**MyAnnotation .m file**

```
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation

- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title andSubTitle:(NSString *)subtitle atCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _title = title;
        _subtitle = subtitle;
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;   
}

@end
```

Then use your class to create the annotation

**Instead of this code**

```
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
MKPinAnnotationView *pointV = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:point reuseIdentifier:nil];
[point setCoordinate:location];
point.title = title;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:pointV.annotation];
```

**Add This Code**

```
MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:title andSubTitle:nil atCoordinate:location];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```